# How to validate email address format?

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am creating a userform on which the user must enter certain information.

For example, I would like to make a condition or code to inform the user that he must enter a valid email address, and not only a msgbox because he can click OK and continue without modifying his email address.

I found this code but I found it hard to understand. What does it mean?

```
Function ValidEmail(eMail As String) As Boolean
    Dim MyRegExp As RegExp
    Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
    Set MyRegExp = New RegExp
    MyRegExp.Pattern = "^[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9.-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$"
    MyRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    MyRegExp.Global = False
    Set myMatches = MyRegExp.Execute(eMail)
    ValidEmail = (myMatches.Count = 1)
    Set myMatches = Nothing
    Set MyRegExp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Will you send a test email with a clickable link to really test the email address entered or just check for the “@“ sign as a token gesture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll break down each line and give a bit more on what the function does.

```
Function ValidEmail(eMail as String) As Boolean
```

this defines the ValidEmail function that will take in a string and return a boolean

```
Dim MyRegExp as RegExp
```

This defines MyRegExp as a regular expression.

```
Dim myMatches as MatchCollection
```

This defines a regular expression match collection. This will hold any matches that are found as defined by our Regular expression.

```
Set MyRegExp = new RegExp
```

Set our MyRegExp variable to a new expression object

```
MyRegExp.Pattern = "^[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9.-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$"
```

Sets the pattern being used to determine a match.

```
MyRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
```

Ignore the difference in case so that A and a are evaluated as just the letter.

```
 MyRegExp.Global = False
```

The regular expression will only look for the first match. if it was true it would find all matches of the pattern in the string.

```
Set myMatches = MyRegExp.Execute(eMail)
```

Executes the pattern matching and assigns a match if any is found. If a match is found a valid email has been found. If a match is not found then nothing was found.

```
 ValidEmail = (myMatches.Count = 1)
```

If our matches contains 1 match we set our function to true to indicate a valid email was found. If the match count is not 1, since global is false and we didn't find the first match then it would be 0, then we did not find a valid email.

```
Set myMatches = Nothing
Set MyRegExp = Nothing
```

Cleaning up the variables we defined. Good practice for any code.

```
End Function
```

Ends the defined function.

---

### The regular expression explained:

In addition you can use https://regex101.com/ to learn about the regular expression "^[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9.-]{2,}.[a-z]{2,4}$".

To over simplify it will look that the string starts with one or more of the values [a-z0-9_.-] then an @ symbol and then 2 or more of theses values [a-z0-9.-] followed by a literal period and 2-4 alphabetical characters at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

A good website to help explain regex is https://regexr.com/4rbh5

When I paste your regex string in, it explains what each piece does.

[image: Example]