# Is there a way to validate email addresses with VBA that do not use VBScript?

Tags: vba

I currently use VBScript to validate email addresess when using VBA. Lately VBScript has been causing problems with anti-virus software, and, Microsoft is going to deprecate it soon. I want my workbooks to perform without issues long into the future...My current code looks like this...

```
Public Function ValidateEmail(address As String) As Boolean
' Validate email address
Dim objRegExp As Object

On Error GoTo errHandler

    ValidateEmail = False
    
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.Pattern = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"

    ValidateEmail = objRegExp.test(address)

    ' Release some memory
    Set objRegExp = Nothing
    
    Exit Function
    
errHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        If Err.Number = 70 Then ' Permission error...likely antivirus software with a VBScript exception
            MsgBox "An error occurred while running the E-Mail Validation procedure. This is most probably " _
            & "due to Antivirus or Malware software preventing the running of any VBScript which this function requires." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & "There may also be another message about the address being invalid, check it manually for correctness.", vbOKOnly, "Error number: " & Err.Number
            Exit Function
        Else
            If MsgBox("An error occurred while running the E-Mail Validation procedure. Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "Error number: " & Err.Number) = vbNo Then
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    Resume Next
    
End Function
```

I have yet to find a simple working solution.

Comment: What is the issue - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate email address format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493634/how-to-validate-email-address-format)

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=281